# Laravel homestead not mapping my code folder

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I am trying to get homestead to work after following the instructions [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead)

I have Virtualbox 5.0.6 and Vagrant 1.7.4 on windows 8. The machine boots up fine(ish) the only problem is that my mapped folder is not present on the vm, meaning when I `vagrant ssh`, the directory `/home/vagrant/` is empty, there is no `Code` directory inside of it. This is a screenshot of the machine booting(it should keep going and saying mapping the folders and stuff):

[image: machine booting]

And this is the content of my `Homestead.yaml` file

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: C:\Users\Khalid\.ssh\id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:\Users\Khalid\.ssh\id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:\work
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Could someone please help, Thanks

EDIT: The full output of `vagrant up --debug` can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/zysc76A2)

Comment: Its weird you should have on start-up something that says `default: Mounting shared folders...` can you open Virtual Box, in the settings of you VM, check the sharing folder, see if you have something if you dont try to add a sharing folder and see if it works or if you have an error - last run `vagrant up --debug` and copy the full log somewhere on pastebin or gist

Comment: @FrédéricHenri After checking the shared folders in Virtual box I found my folder there `D:/work` . the question is updated with the full output of `vagrant up --debug`

Comment: What happens if you add double quotes around `D:\work`?

Comment: weird ... so the virtual box sees it ? what is it mapped to ? can you try replace `/home/vagrant/Code` with `/code` for example and see if you can access `/code` folder from the VM ?

Comment: What is the location of the homestead.yaml file you edited?

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank The file location is `C:\Users\Khalid\.homestead\Homestead.yaml`

Comment: None of the suggestions worked :(  It feels like the stone age working with WAMP here.

Comment: What does `mount` command say, and did you check the system logs for any clues: `/var/log/syslog`. You'll need to connect to the virtual machine first: `homestead ssh`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

sstarlight was on the right track. It's a path name issue. I'm on windows 8 with homestead too and you need to use the forward slashes even in your windows paths.

The below should do the trick!

```
authorize: C:/Users/Khalid/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:/Users/Khalid/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:/work
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
```

I would add to this that you should run the provisioning as per the other answer after you make the change by bringing your homestead up with the --provision flag set.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure and re-verify that the path for the `keys` and `authorize` are correct and run `vagrant up --provision` to re-provision the homestead setup again

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```
 D:\work to D:/work/
```

Comment: No, same thing happened.

Comment: @swapnilsaha I couldn't solve it :\ I had to switch to using wamp back then, until I replaced my windows machine with a mac book.